# jQuery(document).on('click.classname'.......)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, materialize

I was reading through [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html)'s js files, in its "cards.js" file, there are these lines:

```
$(document).on('click.card', '.card', function (e) {
    //something
});
```

I am not unfamiliar with jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function, but I never used custom event as the first parameter. What I don't understand is there seems to be nowhere defining this custom event `click.card`(if it is a custom event), because I only load this `card.js` and another `velocity.min.js` file from the MaterializeCSS package besides jQuery, and I searched `velocity.min.js` there is nothing related to this event. It seems to me that the custom event is in this pattern:`original event`.`classname`, but I tried replacing `card` with other class name and it didn't work.

I tried to look for more information about how to define a custom event but couldn't find anything useful.

My question is how to find where this custom event is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a custom event, this is a [DOM event with a namespace](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/):

`click` is the DOM event, and `card` the event namespace.

If you have multiple handlers on the same element, this can help you discern them. You could remove only this listener (and leave all other `click` listeners):

```
$(document).off('click.card');
```

And you can trigger them manually using `$('...').trigger`:

```
$('.card').trigger('click.card'); // only triggers this specific click listener, not the others
```

[You can find out more about event namespaces here.](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names)